# Using css grid minmax and a href attributes

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am new to using css grid. I am attempting to make a responsive grid of images that differ in sizes. The example that I came up with works perfectly but it seems like I need to define a size `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(84px, max-content));` instead of something like `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, max-content));` if I use `auto-fit`. This makes the `a href` attribute extend the 84px even if the image itself isn't 84px.

Is there a way to use `auto-fit` while also having the rows and columns fit perfectly like they do now, without having to define the size as 84px? Or is there a better way to do this while keeping it simple?

```css
a {
  border: 2px dashed pink;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(84px, max-content));
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.ef {
  background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/84x84/) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  width: 84px;
  height: 84px;
}

.eft {
  background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/16x16/) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.ytt {
  background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/44x44/) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  The grid is fine but the a href extends too far for some reason.
</p>

<section class="grid">
  <a href="/ytt">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ef"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ef"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="eft"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="eft"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ef"></div>
  </a>

 <a href="/ef">
    <div class="eft"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: maybe add `justify-items: center;` to the grid?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Wow, what a simple fix. I used `justify-items: start;` for preference but that did it! Would you be able to explain why that fixed it? Curious for learning.

Comment: by default items will get stretched to fill the grid area since the default alignment is stretch. You already changed this on the cross axis using align-items, we do the same for the main axis using justify-items. You will notice that both properties accept `stretch` as value

Comment: Thanks a lot @TemaniAfif If you'd like to put that into a reply I can give you answer credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `justify-items`. By default items will get stretched to fill the grid area since the default alignment is stretch. You already changed this on the cross axis using `align-items`. We do the same for the main axis using `justify-items`. You can notice that both properties accept stretch as value

```css
a {
  border: 2px dashed pink;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(84px, max-content));
  align-items: center;
  justify-items:center;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.ef {
  background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/84x84/) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  width: 84px;
  height: 84px;
}

.eft {
  background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/16x16/) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.ytt {
  background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/44x44/) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  The grid is fine but the a href extends too far for some reason.
</p>

<section class="grid">
  <a href="/ytt">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ef"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ef"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="eft"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="eft"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ef"></div>
  </a>

 <a href="/ef">
    <div class="eft"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>

  <a href="/ef">
    <div class="ytt"></div>
  </a>
</section>
```